# Mysqli DELETE not working with variable

Tags: php, mysqli

I'll jump straight into it. Using php I'm having a problem deleting a record from the database if i use a variable as the value. The line of code below works perfectly

```
mysqli_query($con,"DELETE FROM highScores WHERE Name='David'");
```

But the name of the user will change, therefore I need to declare it as a variable. I've tried all kinds of variations but nothing seems to work. My latest failed attempt was the code below, which is the way i declare a varible when i'm inserting.

```
mysqli_query($con,"DELETE FROM highScores WHERE Name='{$name}'");
```

Comment: Did you try without the curly brackets?  That should work. "mysqli_query($con,"DELETE FROM highScores WHERE Name='$name'");"   But ideally you should 'sanitize' any variables you use in sql queries, especially if they come from public user input

Comment: Does your query return an error?

Comment: Rather than using '{$name}' use directly '$name'

Comment: @MrVimes I tried that with no success. I also tried to concatinate with periods, that also didn't work.

Comment: ... Maybe $name doesn't contain what you think it does then.  Try echoing it beforehand.  I find that echoing stuff is a good way to debug code.

Better yet - echo the entire sql query before using it in your call to mysqli_query()

Comment: '{$name}' should be working just fine, dunno why everyone is telling you to concatenate, the problem isnt there, the problem is likely that $name contains not what you think it does, or nothing at all

Comment: Try this, and see what gets output..  echo "DELETE FROM highScores WHERE Name='{$name}'";

Comment: @MrVimes Thanks a lot! this fixed it. Your comment "Maybe $name doesn't contain what you think it does then" made me check it out. I was declaring the $name below my DELETE. I didn't think it mattered as the value is cookie driven, but it seems that it did matter. If you put it in the answer i'll mark it as correct.

Comment: I wasn't going to answer because someone else also implied (before I) that $name might not contain what it should, but I decided to answer to suggest the echoing the query as a debug tool thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In situations like this it is good to check that variables actually contain something you expect it to.  And I find also that echoing entire query strings is a good way to find out why a query isn''t working.

```
$sqlquery = "DELETE FROM highScores WHERE Name='{$name}'";

// have a look at the query...

echo "<pre>$sqlquery</pre>";

// use it...

mysqli_query($conn,$sqlquery);
```

I should warn you that if $name comes from somewhere untrusted, such as a publicly viewable html form, then it needs to be made 'safe' before using it in a query.   Look into '[prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statements)'.  Once you know your code is correctly populating your variable, make sure it is made safe before putting it in your query.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get it running:

```
mysqli_query($con,"DELETE FROM highScores WHERE Name='".$name."'");
```

Make sure `$name` is a proper formed string like `string(5) David`, otherwise it might not lead to the desired results or may even break your query completely. You can make sure of this if you put a [`mysqli_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) like this

```
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$name);
```

before you execute the query

Comment: In PHP you don't need to break out of a string to insert a variable,  you can do Name='$name' and it should work.

Comment: I know, but it better highlights the code if you break them out anyway!

Comment: I want to say 'ok' but stackoverflow won't allow my comment to be that short :D

Comment: Please `var_dump($name);` and post the result.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if..
{$variable} is valid in a query.

The way I insert a variable into a query, is called concentration.

```
mysqli_query($con,"DELETE FROM highScores WHERE Name='" . $name . "'");
```

The period adds 2 strings together.

However, what you're trying to do is vulnerable to SQL injection. If I were you, I'd be careful on what could be inside  $name.

EDIT: My mistake, I'm used to a class that inserts the quotes for me.

Comment: {$variable} is perfectly valid, and your suggestion is not good...as name needs single quotes around it

Comment: It is not a query but PHP string.

Comment: For the record this works, i checked it out while debugging a similar problem. If doing it this way is best practice, then I don't know, but it definitely works.

Answer (score 0):

I landed here while searching for solutions to the same problem, but just discovered my database user didn't have delete privileges. I had earlier removed this privilege for security reasons.